# How to retrieve URL nested inside JSONObject?

Tags: java, json

I am learning JavaEE, I have a JSONObject, and I need to retrieve a nested propriety "link", that is a URL to a PDF file (inside the JSON). Everything I try gives me error. Any hints or help would be appreciated.

The JSON: https://kalilcamera.com.br/teste.json (i want the URL http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf inside this JSON)

My parse (working):
JSONObject testJson = new JSONObject( HttpUtil.send("POST", "https://kalilcamera.com.br/teste.json", "s", null).getResponseMessage());

My try to get the Link:
String urlPrescricaoMemedPDF = testJson.get("link").toString();
no matter what i try, gives me error.

my code from the debug perspective (Easy to undersand):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/584LR.png

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to go through your json to get to the part where you can call get. Think of it as an nested Map, if you call get for something that is 3 layers down, you wont get anything usefull.

Second use `getAsString` instead of `toString`

```
final HttpRequest get = HttpRequest.newBuilder(URI.create("https://kalilcamera.com.br/teste.json"))
            .GET()
            .build();

final HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newHttpClient();

final HttpResponse<String> response = httpClient.send(get, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
final JsonObject bodyJson = JsonParser.parseString(response.body()).getAsJsonObject();
final JsonElement data = bodyJson.get("data");
final JsonElement zero = data.getAsJsonArray().get(0);
final JsonElement attributes = zero.getAsJsonObject().get("attributes");
final JsonElement link = attributes.getAsJsonObject().get("link");
System.out.println(link.getAsString());
```

prints : `http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf`

Comment: This method doesn't exist

Comment: then what library are you using?
I saw you using GSON, and with GSON it works

Comment: It's JSON-Java, the Java EE-compatible implementation from json.org.

Answer (score 0):

Use `object.getString("link")` instead of `get("link")`.

Comment: Still returns null.